# Publishing mvc5 C# publish folder work on developer machine but not on other?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

publish folder MVC5 it work on developer machine on iis7.5 but not work on other machine on iis 7.5 which is issue? 
Also It through error on other machine
i)HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
ii)HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

Comment: Are you sure the file is on the server with IIS?  Are you sure the user the app pool for the website is running under has access to the file?

Comment: Yes sir i will check all stuff beacuse same publish folder work on developer machine iis but not work on other machine